# Submit a Form via a Reveal Modal

Tags: php, ajax, forms, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I am trying to submit a form and open a modal with the forms post data on it.
Modal works fine but the form post is not passed through.

I have tried jquery/ajax but no luck.

```
<form id="frmTractors" method="post" action='process.php'>
    <select id="tractor" name="tractor_number">
       <options...>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="process.php" />
</form>

<!-- ### MODAL ### -->
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal></div>
```

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle?

Comment: Hi, I've made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xy9otv55/1/ but can't make it work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running something similar on a site:

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="processURL" value="process.php">
    <select id="tractor" name="tractor_number">
       <options...>
    </select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {  
    $( "#tractor" ).change(function(){
        var url = $('#processURL').val();
        var tractor_number = $(this).val();                 
        var postit = $.post( url, {tractor_number:tractor_number});     
        postit.done(function( data ) {

        $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');

        });     
    }); 
});
```

You don't need a form, just a hidden input to hold your process file URL.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked great. Only thing I needed to add to it was the url var to the foundation function: $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open', url);

Comment: You are welcomed... I love Foundation. It is far easier to learn then bootstrap, light weight and meets the requirements of most small businesses for an effective website.